# Azure: whats the difference between "basic" and "standard" SKU for public IP, and which should I Chose?

Tags: networking, azure

to create a public IP for a server, so it can "see" the outside world, and so I can SSH to it, I need to create a static ip.  This can be "standard" or "Basic". What is the difference, and which should I chose?

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the documentation:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/public-ip-addresses#sku

Comment: I had already read that document twice before posting, and it didnt help. There are a list of features of basic and standard, and I cant tell the difference - they appear to be the same thing with very subtle differences. One support regionals which I dont need. Both support static which is always what I need.   I dont know how to choose, or what the impact is of choosing the wrong one.

Comment: It depends on what you need to to with it. As an example, if you need to attach a public IP address to a Standard (as opposed to Basic) load balancer, you'll need a Standard public IP.